# Please how to set fix size of box in form view odoo 8

Tags: odoo

How can I fix the size of a box in a form view on `0doo 8`

In `XMLù group :

```
<field name="taxe"/>
```

In `py` file :

```
'taxe' : fields.selection([('17','17 %'),('12','12 %'),('10','10 %')],'Taxe Etablissement'),
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the attribute style on your xml field definition, for example:

```
<field name="field_x" style="width:50%%" />
```

or

```
<field name="field_y" style="width:100px" />
```

Percentage will use the space what was given by the parent element. So if you uses 2 columns layout (typical odoo groups) 50% will use like 25% of full width.
Don't forget to escape '%'.